# Why after clicking it's not doing task 2?

Tags: ios, swift

On click I need to do two actions. Showing the message and then going to another user interface. But here only the TASK 1 is executing but not TASK 2.

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    // TASK 1 - OK    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Task 1", message: "Test message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))    
    self.present(alert, animated: true)

    // TASK 2 - FAIL (does not execute)
    let x = XyzViewController()
    x.body = "test";
    self.present(x, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Look in the console. There should be an error message telling you the problem.

Comment: And your task 2 code is executing. Use the debugger to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your task in inside the action, reason the `UIAlertController` is a viewcontroller, it is already presented, if you want to present the same view in additionally, you need to dismiss the Current VC first, but in here is not a good pratice to do.

```
// TASK 1 - OK    
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Task 1", 
                              message: "Test message.", 
                              preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
  // perhaps use action.title here
  let x = XyzViewController()
  x.body = "test";
  self.present(x, animated: false, completion: nil)
})

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```